# Getting path not found error while executing GetConfig section from a console app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to execute the below code from a console app.

```
ConfigurationSection aggregatedFileSection = (ConfigurationSection)config.GetSection("Aggregation.FileAggregationConfig");  // this is inside a web.config of main web project
```

The below line is in web.config.

```
<Aggregation.FileAggregationConfig configSource="config\common\MyAggregation.Config" />
```

The above aggregation has a http handler attached to it in web.confg inside that project.

```
<section name="Aggregation.FileAggregationConfig" type="WebProj.AggregationConfigHanler, WEBPROJ"/>
```

As I am getting the config section from console app and it is unable to find the Webproj path while executing handler which is inside web project.
and throwing error , path cannot found while executing httphandler

Can you please let me know if you know any way to give path in the console app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config file will be read from your `active` project and in this case is your console app config file. you should embed items in web.config in your console app.

Comment: i am loading web.config of main project from the console app. I am storing the web.config path of main project in the console app , app.config. I am able to get all config sections. As this particular one has httphandler code inside that project , I couldn't get it running.Any other ideas??

Comment: @gov, you can not get handler class? you should copy related dll's of handler class inside your console output, or by adding it as reference do this.

Comment: thanks very much , i added the mainproj dll and its working , thank you very much once agian , i will mark yours as answer.